# Announce a Div without changing content of the div at certain point in time

Tags: html, accessibility

Is there any way to make a certain div announce at particular point in time using certain aria attribute without changing its content? aria-live announces only when we change the content in that div.

For e.g. In my case when a page loads here is the state for two containers

Container A : Show

Container B: Hide

After 5 seconds, I toggle the state of both container

Container A: Hide

Container B: Show

What I want to do at this point is announce certain property of container B. Note that, I am not changing the content of any container, only toggling the show/hide behavior, therefore live regions solution (including role="status/alert") will also not work.

Comment: What if it takes 10 seconds to announce Container A? should it then announce both at the same time? ... but in general, this sounds like a not so good approach and I can't really see the benefits of doing this?

Comment: This goes against WCAG principles of things happening without informing the user. Do you want to elaborate on **why** you are doing this as there may be a better solution (or if it is a valid use case we can offer an answer...but golden rule of accessibility is try the "right" way to do things first and fall back to tricks when all else fails!).

Comment: It is difficult to know what you're trying to achieve and may be there is more correct way to do. Here is one technique that is used for [Toggletips with live regions](https://inclusive-components.design/tooltips-toggletips/#toggletipswithliveregions) which you can use.